# Invert the canvas' drawText()

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

Been looking for a way to invert the text when I draw the texts on my `canvas` object. I could not find any related problem here in SO. (Maybe I am using the wrong keywords.) This is what I want to achieve with `drawText()`:

[image]

Is this feature available in `android.graphics` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my issue.

```
String textToWrite = "Hello World";
int padding = 5;
int paddingTop = padding;
int paddingBottom = padding;
int paddingLeft = padding;
int paddingRight = padding;

Rect bounds = new Rect();
mPaint.getTextBounds(textToWrite, 0, textToWrite.length(), bounds);

mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bounds.width() + paddingLeft + paddingRight,
        bounds.height() + paddingTop + paddingBottom,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height() - padding)/2 ;
canvas.drawText(textToWrite, paddingLeft, y, mPaint);
```

If you want to add this inverted text to the rest of your canvas, simply draw `bitmap` to your global canvas like so:

```
mOriginalCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mCurrentX, mCurrentY, mOriginalPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any similar feature in `android.graphics`.

But your use case is similar to the Night Mode feature. There are some ways to achieve this for example:

1. Using different styles for your `TextView`
2. Create a custom `TextView` to invert the background and text colors.